# Removing the FeedBurner redirect

Tags: feed, feedburner

When I set up my blog i was using the default RSS feed which worked fine. Then I switched it to using FeedBurner using the FeedSmith plugin which also worked without issue.

Now though I want to go back to the default WordPress feed instead. I've removed WordSmith but www.mydomain.com/feed/ still gets redirected to FeedBurner and I can't find a way to stop it.

It's not mentioned in my .htaccess file and the database rewrite_rules only changes that URL to use index.php?feed=rss2 which is the bit that redirects to FeedBurner.

I can use feed=rss or atom to get the wordPress generated feeds but I want the defautl one to use it as well. I've poked around a little in the source to try and trace it but to no avail so far.

Does anyone know where this unwanted redirect might be hiding itself?

As a temporary workaround I'll set the rewrite_rules to redirect it to the RSS 1 feed but would rather it went to the RSS 2 one.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the **Settings - Permalinks** page to update the rewrite rules. See if it fixes it.

Comment: I saved the config there but no change. I should have time to check through in the morning and see if I can narrow down exactly where in the code the redirect is happening and trace it back to a setting.